# Relatively prime solutions of the equation $7x^2+59y^2=3^n$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

We seek integer solutions of the equation $7x^2+59y^2=3^n$ where $x$ and $y$ are relatively prime. Does there exist infinitely many such solutions?

Comment: Hint: notice the right-hand side of the equation is a power of $3$, and then note the ending digit of each power of $3$: the ones digit of all of the powers of three sequentially go $3$, $9$, $7$, $1$, $3$, $9$, $7$, $1$, and so on. From this information, what does this tell you about the left-hand side?

Comment: @Decaf-Math: what is does tell you? The LHS is either $0$ or $3\pmod{4}$, hence $n$ has to be odd, but $3^5$ *is* number of such form, $59\cdot 2^2+7\cdot 1^2$. If numbers of the form $7x^2+59y^2$ formed a semigroup, that would be enough to state the existence of infinite solutions.

Comment: As noted $n$ must be odd, so reducing mod $8$ shows that $x\equiv0\pmod{4}$ and $y\equiv1\pmod{2}$.